# Get value of input field after button click

Tags: jquery, html

Let's look at table of inputs and buttons:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type=\"number\" name=\"name1\">
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type=\"button\" class=\"button\">Button</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

The table is bigger, and contains many rows of the same structure as above.

How to, using jquery, get value of input next to the button on click?

I can access the field by using

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
    $(this).parent().prev() // this is the input type
});
```

but calling `.val()` on it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a large table and you are going to be doing this a lot, I would suggest using [HTML5 data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to link the button with the input field:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input id="input-1" type=\"number\" name=\"name1\">
  </td>
  <td>
    <button data-input=\"#input-1\"type=\"button\" class=\"button\">Button</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Notice the `id` attribute on the input matches the `data-input` attribute on the button.  Now you can do something like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var input = $(this).data('input');
    var value = $(input).val();

    // Do something with the value
});
```

#### Update

If the relationship is not one-to-one, you would have to modify the structure a bit.  You couldn't use the `id` attribute, since id's must be unique.  Instead, you could give each input a data attribute, such as:

```
<input data-group="1" type=\"number\" name=\"name1\">
```

And your button would have a corresponding data attribute:

```
<button data-input=\"1\"type=\"button\" class=\"button\">Button</button>
```

Then in your click handler, you could do this:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var input_group = $(this).data('input');
    var inputs = $('input[data-group="' + input_group + '"]');
    var values = [];

    // Read the values into an array
    $.each(inputs, function(i, input) {
        values.push(input.val());
    });

    // Do something with the values...
});
```

Comment: Would this method work if it wasn't one-to-one connection, but let's say 2 or 3 inputs per one button?